# Pythagorean theorem in Riemann metrics of non constant curvature

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I was reading this interesting article by Givental

[Givental, Alexander. "The Pythagorean theorem: What is it about?" Amer. Math. Monthly 113 (2006), no. 3, 261–265](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27641894)

And my attention was caught by this passage:

"*This explains why the Pythagorean theorem is a genuinely Euclidean phenomenon (and not only in the
historical sense of the word): among all Riemannian metrics of constant curvature only the Euclidean one admits nontrivial conformal isometries.*"

So that's the question: there exist Riemannian metrics of non constant curvature admitting nontrivial conformal isometries? If so, the Pythagorean theorem holds on them?

[image]

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447199/pythagorean-theorem-in-riemann-metrics-of-non-constant-curvature